# Get HTML after Javascript - server application

Tags: php, javascript, c++, html, linux

I need a way to get full HTML content of a page after Javascript has loaded and executed.
It must be built as server side application (Linux) and can include any 3rd party software (some browser without GUI or anything else that could help).

Can this be done using PHP or Cpp, if not what other options do I have ?
This is a strange subject - I'm having hard time finding information on it.
Thank you for any help.

So I found something on subject - [Any way to run Firefox with GreaseMonkey scripts without a GUI/X session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109570/any-way-to-run-firefox-with-greasemonkey-scripts-without-a-gui-x-session) , but if anyone has something to add  I'm still open for suggestions.

It seems that Node.js could help

Comment: You can load HTML markup into empty containers using an ajax approach. Look into templating for alternative approaches using server side syntaxes.

Comment: agreed strange - what are you doing? scraping content?

Comment: What a question, of course with permission :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this http://phantomjs.org/. It uses JavaScript but lets you do anything you could do in a web browser (including viewing current state of the DOM).